# Unresolved reference issue in PyCharm again￼

Tags: pycharm

pycharm version is 2019.1

```
￼   pip --version
    pip 19.0.3 from ~/myProject/venv_dao/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip-19.0.3-py3.6.egg/pip (python 3.6)
```

My project can work, but why there are so many 'Unresolved reference'.

[image: unresolved]

This is my virtualvenv:
[image: my virtualvenv]

Answer (score 0):

I update pycharm2019.2 solve this issue.